# Why do some max-width media queries use a .98px

Tags: bootstrap-4, media-queries

Noticed recently that Bootstrap V4 changed their media queries from `@media screen and (max-width: 991)` to `@media screen and (max-width: 991.98px)`. Does that extra .98px change anything? Does it provide some type of benefit and/or fix?

I can't seem to find anything in particular mentioning why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've answered a related [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53832987/how-can-i-add-custom-breakpoint-in-bootstrap-4-and-use-it-for-both-up-and-down/53834741)

Bootstrap 4 subtracts `.02px` from the top end of each breakpoint to ensure there are no overlapping breakpoints.

This is because CSS media queries only allow for "equal to" logic and not "less than" as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14534477/how-to-use-or-greater-than-and-less-than-symbols-in-media-queries)

Using `.02px` less, instead of `1px` less, provides better granularity between breakpoints.

Comment: Wouldn't the obvious answer to overlapping breakpoints be to just subtract `1px` instead?

Comment: Could elaborate on the "provides better granularity" point? Or if you have any articles regarding that

Comment: High DPI devices may allow for fractional pixel viewport sizes like the nearest 0.5px. With Windows supporting quirky scales like 175%, you can end up with even crazier values like 998.857px.